# My python manage.py runserver Not Working?

Tags: python, django

**recently I have been learning Django and what I did was:
1 pip install Django
2 make a file
3 run server
My code was: `python manage.py runserver`
but when I wanted to make the server it showed 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file.
please someone help (Am very noob at Django )**

Comment: Which Python are you trying to use? In Linux, 'python' was used for Python 2  interpreter. Now Python 2 is deprecated and not longer supported. You should use python3 command to run Python 3. Also you'd better check twice if your Django manual isn't outdated. Please provide some info on which operating system are you using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it show `'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file.` it means that you do not have installed python in your pc. You can install it using the official page:

https://www.python.org/downloads/

Don't forget to check "Add python to environment variables"! :)